# Using CIFilter within GPUImage framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, gpuimage, cifilter

I've search around and couldn't find an answer, If it's possible to use CIFilter, for example : `CICrystallize` into GPUImage. I needed to create about 70-80 UIImages from this filter(for example), and the basic Core Image implementation were just too slow. SO i thought if i could use the great GPUImage mechanism it'll produce great results. Bottom line.

**Is it possible to use CIFilter, `CICrystallize` I.E, within GPUImage, for still image processing?**

Comment: Are you asking if there's an implementation of what CICrystallize does within GPUImage? Not at present, but it looks like a variant of what was started in the Voronoi diagram support in GPUImage. Are you sure that you're using a GPU-based Core Image context and not falling back to a CPU-based one?

Comment: Hey @BradLarson . Thanks for replying. I asked if it's possible to use the CIFilter CICrystallize as CIFilter CICrystallize within GPU.Sorry for my ignorance, but i'm not completely sure what "you're using a GPU-based Core Image context and not falling back to a CPU-based one?"  -. Eventually i've came up with a work around(which was surprisingly, a bit too good to be honest) implementation of CIFilter Core Image mechanism, with EAGLContext, Which produced very fast results. Tho it still cannot overcome(lol) your great framework!

Comment: @BradLarson I read the op question as 'is it possible to wrap a CIFilter within a custom GPUImageFilter?' eg. a custom GPUImageFilter which would call CIPhotoEffectChrome CIFilter.